# How to release memory after call gsoap proxy

Tags: memory-leaks, gsoap

I inherited some C++ code which calls SOAP service using gsoap generated proxy. The purpose of the code is to retrieve some data from Web Service. Code I am working is running on Linux, Web Service is Windows service. Functionality works fine - I am getting my data. But when I run it with valgrind it shows serious leeks. And no wander. When i looked at the definition of the response structure i found that it is consists of many pointers and I don't see that anywhere  these pointers are released.

I tried to release them in a naive and straightforward way like delete p or free (p). As a result valgrind started to report that i have mismatched deletes. I looked a little bit in stackoverflow and Genevia, couldn't find any definite answer. Also I tried to use soap_destroy function, but it didn't eliminate my leaks.

My main function (abridged )which uses gsoap proxy looks like this:

```
bool ParcDataSvcProxy::GetTradingHours(vector<TradingHours>& tradingHours, vector<int>& filter, string& errorMessage)
{
    tradingHours.clear();
    BasicHttpBinding_USCOREIParcDataServiceProxy proxy;
    struct soap * soap_ptr = proxy.soap;
    soap_set_version(soap_ptr, 1);
    proxy.soap_endpoint = _url.c_str();
    _ns1__GetTradingHours* req = new _ns1__GetTradingHours();
    int *sourceId = NULL;
    req->sourceID = sourceId;
    _ns1__GetTradingHoursResponse response;
    try
    {
        int  ret = proxy.GetTradingHours(req, response);
        int cnt = response.GetTradingHoursResult->TradingHours.size();
        for (int ni = 0; ni < cnt; ni++)
        {
            TradingHours xyz;
            auto trhour = response.GetTradingHoursResult->TradingHours[ni];
            // do something with data
        }
    }
    catch (exception& ex)
    {
        errorMessage = "Error in GetTradingHours. url=";
        errorMessage += proxy.soap_endpoint;
        errorMessage += " ";
        errorMessage += ex.what();
        delete req;
        return false;
    }
    soap_destroy(soap_ptr);
    soap_destroy(response.soap);
    return true;

}
```

The definition of my response class (generated by gsoap)
looks like

```
class SOAP_CMAC _ns1__GetTradingHoursResponse {
      public:
        /// Optional element 'ns1:GetTradingHoursResult' of XSD type 'ns4:ArrayOfTradingHours'
        ns4__ArrayOfTradingHours *GetTradingHoursResult;
        /// Context that manages this object
        struct soap *soap;
      public:
        /// Return unique type id SOAP_TYPE__ns1__GetTradingHoursResponse
        virtual long soap_type(void) const { return SOAP_TYPE__ns1__GetTradingHoursResponse; }
        /// (Re)set members to default values
        virtual void soap_default(struct soap*);
........................
}
```

So again, the question is: are there any way to release in a simple way my response object.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After calling `soap_destroy()` you will need to call `soap_end()` to remove deserialized POD structures from gsoap-managed memory. The `soap_destroy()` call only removes C++ objects allocated in managed memory:

```
    soap_destroy(soap_ptr);
    soap_end(soap_ptr);
    soap_destroy(response.soap);
    soap_end(response.soap);
```

The above is C-style function calling. Alternatively, in C++ use the `destroy()` method that calls both `soap_destroy()` and `soap_end()` on the engine context:

```
    soap_ptr->destroy();
    response.soap->destroy();
```

Finally, I should point out that `soap_ptr` and `response.soap` are the same, because the `response.soap` engine context pointer is set to `proxy.soap`, because this is the proxy that deserialized the data. So you can just invoke `proxy.destroy()` to release managed memory:

```
    proxy.destroy();
```

If you need to retain any data before you destroy it, then use the soapcpp2-generated deep copy functions and methods using soapcpp2 option `-Ecd`. For more info, see:

- https://www.genivia.com/doc/guide/html/index.html#deep
- https://www.genivia.com/doc/databinding/html/index.html#memory2

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It worked. Almost... valgrind still reports 24 bytes definitely lost. Cannot figure out what is the leak. Does protobuf allocates some global memory?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It worked. Almost... For some reason it didn't release request (req). So i had to do it "manually": delete req->soap;delete req->sourceID; delete req;     I am curious if there more "advanced" way to delete req. But overall the problem is solved -- thank you again

Comment: Again Dr. Alex RE, thank you very much for your help. My last issue with not releasing request was an easy one thanks to your hint. I didn't realize that in gsoap we dont do just new or malloc. When i changed my 
_ns1__GetTradingHours* req = new _ns1__GetTradingHours();

to 

_ns1__GetTradingHours* req = soap_new__ns1__GetTradingHours(soap_ptr);

everything started to be good